# What is difference SelectManyMenu and SelectCheckboxMenu in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

SelectManyMenu - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyMenu.xhtml
SelectCheckboxMenu  - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml

They look similar. I need to know when should I use SelectCheckboxMenu over SelectManyMenu. Or they do the same purpose?

Any historical stories behind these 2 components?

Comment: Well, do you want a drop down, or a scrollable list? Do you want to show images in the selections, or just text? Try both and pick one that fits your project's needs.

Comment: @AliCheaito is right... the difference is in appearance In a real good forms standard (XForms) both are have been called a 'select(many) with just different appearances

Comment: @AliCheaito Thank You I did not notice that before. I was so sleepy and headache. Please put your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, do you want a drop down, or a scrollable list? Do you want to show images in the selections, or just text? Try both and pick one that fits your project's needs.